# Jquery to show the Content as a link

Tags: css, ajax, jquery-ui, jquery

Using `.NET MVC3`following is my view,

```
  function Dispalymaingrid () { 
  var Geo=$('#ddlGeo').val();
  var Vertical=$('#ddlVertical').val();
  var Month=$('#ddlMonth').val();
  if(Vertical=="All")
  {
  var Flag=1;
  }
  else
  {
  var Flag=2;
  }      
    $.ajax({
    url:"@Url.Action("TRUnutilizedOwnershipChange", "TravelReady")",
    datatype:"html",
    type:"post",
    data:{strGeo:Geo,strVertical:Vertical,intMonth:Month,intFlag:Flag},
    error:function(){},
    success:function(data){
    $('.travTableContent').empty();
                    var text3=data.data.lstunutilizedownershipentities;
                    for( var item in text3)
                    {
                    $('<tr />').html(text3[item]).appendTo('.travTableContent');
                    $('<td />').html(text3[item].CurrentOwnership).appendTo('.travTableContent');
                    $('<td />').html(text3[item].cnt).appendTo('.travTableContent');                        
                    }                        
      }     
    }); 
  }
```

I want to get the count value from this line

```
$('<td />').html(text3[item].cnt).appendTo('.travTableContent');
```

I want to see this as a link what is the possible css prperty to `$('<td />')` in this

Comment: Put your `css()` function after `.html(text3[item].cnt)` , Also declaration variable `Flag` inside if-block is not accessible outside this block

Comment: show us your html code, related to the class `.travTableContent`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$('<td />').html('<a href="#your-link">' + text3[item].cnt + '</a>').appendTo('.travTableContent');
```

Update: Passing `text3[item].CurrentOwnership` as `argument` to `GetDetail()`

```
$('<td />').html('<a href="#" onclick="GetDetail(\'' + text3[item].CurrentOwnership + '\');">' + text3[item].cnt + '</a>').appendTo('.travTableContent');
```

Comment: Thank You so much for the Response it's working.                 one more question,                                    $('<td />').html('<a href="#" onclick="javascript:GetDetail();">' + text3[item].cnt + '</a>').appendTo('.travTableContent');                                               How can i pass 'text3[item].CurrentOwnership' this as a argument for GetDetail() javascript function?

Comment: Answer updated for that, `Update: Passing text3[item].CurrentOwnership as argument to GetDetail()`